# Calculating $P(X=Y)$ for geometrically distributed random variables

Tags: probability

I want to calculate $P(X=Y)$, where $X,Y$ are independent and geometrically distributed, which means: $P(X=k) = P(Y=k) = p(1-p)^k$, $k \in \mathbb N_0$ and $p \in (0,1)$.

Can anybody tell me how to do this? I'm afraid I don't have an idea..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you do not understand what the Question asks?  Saying "I don't have an idea" leaves the Reader uncertain as to the extent of help you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know of the tower property?

It says that

$P(X=Y) = \mathbb{E}[P(X=Y|Y)].$

So expanding on the right hand side, I get:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X=Y|Y=k)P(Y=k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k|Y=k)P(Y=k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)P(Y=k).$

EDIT: In fact, there's an easier way, if you don't know this tower property: When is $X=Y$? This is the case, exactly when both $X=0$ and $Y=0$, OR if both $X=1$ and $Y=1$, OR etc... So we have:

$P(X=Y) = P(X=0,Y=0) + P(X=1,Y=1) + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X=k,Y=k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X=k)P(Y=k),$

where in the last step, I use independence.

Comment: In this case I think it is easier to just use independence than to invoke conditional expectation ;)

Comment: @Math1000 agreed. :)